# SignalR push data Server to Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, signalr

I have 2 separate servers one for the WebApp and one for SignalR (IIS8/WinSvr12)

Clients (browsers) connect to the WebApp server to request web pages and also maintain a persistent connection to the separate SignalR server.

I have everything setup and working correctly.

Periodically I need my BLL (hosted on the WebApp server) to push data to the clients connected via the SignalR server.

I have created a simple .NET SignalR client Class in my BLL to push data to the clients.

I am finding that I need to establish a connection each and every time I send data from the WebApp server to the SignalR server.

Does anybody see anything wrong with maintaining the connection/proxy inside a Static variable so that it can be shared?

Here is my code:

```
Public Class ChatHub

    Private Shared Property Connection As HubConnection 'the connection is shared across all instances
    Private Shared Property Proxy As IHubProxy 'the proxy is shared across all instances

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Establishes an unauthenticated connection to the SignalR server.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()

        'set connection to server:
        If IsNothing(Connection) Then
            Connection = New HubConnection("http://myserver/signalr")
        End If

        'define hub proxy to connect to:
        If IsNothing(Proxy) Then
            Proxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("chatHub")
        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sends a message asynchronously. 
    ''' </summary>
    Public Async Sub SendMessageAsync(message As String)

        'establish connection:
        If Connection.State = ConnectionState.Disconnected Then

            'Two way communication is not required as we are only pushing data to the signalR server.
            'Therefore we should use ServerSentEventsTransport as it is more efficient than websockets.
            'Explicitly setting the transport type speeds up connection - otherwise connection transport is auto detected:
            Await Connection.Start(New ServerSentEventsTransport())

        End If

        'send message:
        If Connection.State = ConnectionState.Connected Then
            Await Proxy.Invoke("send", message)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

I then use the class like so from various functions in the BLL.

```
Dim chatHubDemo As New BLL.SignalR.ChatHub()
chatHubDemo.SendMessageAsync(message)
```

Note: The Connection and Proxy variables are 'Shared' (statics) so the connection need not be established every time I utilize the class.

Everything is working OK and the connection is being maintained and reused as expected.

I cannot find any documentation that details how to maintain a connection from a webserver to the signalR and the best practice for doing so.

**Does anybody see any issues that may arise by maintaining a persistent connection using statics?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I ended up writing, it is working very well.

It allows me to push data to clients (using the signalr .net client) by initiating the request from the web server business logic:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports
Imports System.Threading.Tasks


''' <summary>
''' Methods and properties that relate to the Communication Hub.
''' Use to push data from the Server to the Client via SignalR.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' We are using shared variables, we can help prevent race conditions by initiating this class by calling the StartUp method from the application_start event
''' </remarks>
Public Class CommHub

    Private Shared Property Connection As HubConnection
    Private Shared Property Proxy As IHubProxy
    Private Shared ReadOnly _connectionLock As Object = New Object

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Start up the connection to the realtime communication servers.
    ''' Call on application_start event.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Sub Startup()
        Task.Run(Async Function()
                     'async must be run on a new thread:
                     Dim commHub As New CommHub
                     Await commHub.ConnectAsync()
                 End Function)
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Establishes an authenticated connection to the SignalR server.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Async Function ConnectAsync() As Tasks.Task

        'set connection to server:
        If IsNothing(Connection) Then
            SyncLock _connectionLock
                If IsNothing(Connection) Then

                    Dim realtimeUrl As String = "http://myserver/signalr"

                    Connection = New HubConnection(realtimeUrl)

                    'OPTIONAL:
                    'add custom headers:
                    'Connection.Headers.Add("headername", "headervalue")

                    'OPTIONAL:
                    'get realtime authentication cookie with permission to communicate with the realtime servers:
                    'Dim authCookie As Net.Cookie = Code_to_get_your_auth_cookie
                    'Connection.CookieContainer = New Net.CookieContainer
                    'Connection.CookieContainer.Add(authCookie)

                    'define hub proxy to connect to:
                    Proxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("commHub")

                End If
            End SyncLock
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(Connection) Then
            Dim myConnection As HubConnection = Connection ' get pointer reference to shared object
            If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Disconnected Then
                Try
                    'Two way communication is not required as we are only pushing data to the signalR server.
                    'Therefore we should use ServerSentEventsTransport as it is more efficient than websockets.
                    'Explicitly setting the transport type speeds up connection - otherwise connection transport is auto detected:
                    Await myConnection.Start(New ServerSentEventsTransport())

                Catch ex As Exception
                    'catch multiple connection attempts
                    'do nothing
                End Try
            End If
        End If

    End Function




    Public Enum CounterTypes As Integer
        Messages
        Requests
        Notifications
    End Enum

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Updates the counter on the specified client in realtime.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="mbrID">The unique id of the client.</param>
    ''' <param name="counterType">The type of counter.</param>
    ''' <param name="value">The value of the counter.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Friend Shared Async Sub UpdateCounterAsync(mbrID As Integer, counterType As CounterTypes, value As Integer)

        're-establish connection if it has been dropped 
        'otherwise reuses the existing connection 
        Dim commHub As New CommHub
        Await commHub.ConnectAsync()

        'call server side method:
        If Not IsNothing(Connection) Then
            Dim myConnection As HubConnection = Connection 'get pointer reference to shared object
            If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Connected Then

                Dim myProxy As IHubProxy = Proxy 'get pointer reference to shared object
                If Not IsNothing(myProxy) Then

                    'invoke method on signalR server:
                    Await myProxy.Invoke("UpdateCounter", mbrID, counterType.ToString, value)

                End If

            End If
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

I can then push data to clients by simply calling methods from my BLL like so:

```
Await CommHub.UpdateCounterAsync(12731, CommHub.CounterTypes.Messages, 10)
```

Eg: user id 12731 has 10 new messages

Remember to call the the StartUp method from your application_start event like so:

```
CommHub.StartUp();
```

This will help prevent race conditions by establish the connection to the server on start up.

Comment: What is `UpdateCounter` being called from ` myProxy.Invoke`?

Comment: UpdateCounter is one of the methods I have written on my signalR server. Use the above example to invoke your own methods.